# Nhibernate error in stored procedure, Procedure GetLastUsed has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, nhibernate

I received the error 
 "Procedure GetClientLastUsed has no parameters and arguments were supplied."
when running a stored procedure using NHibernate.

I have my stored procedure like this:

```
USE [EnergyBL]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetClientLastUsed]    Script Date: 11/13/2014 10:53:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetClientLastUsed] @ClientID as varchar(50)
/*
Object:  GetClientLastUsed
Description: Returns the last time a client was used to create a workorder

Usage: EXEC GetClientLastUsed

Returns:     0  Successful completion

$Workfile: GetClientLastUsed.sql $
$Revision: 1.0 $
$Author: Nathan R. Meunier $
Created: 2014-11-13 $ModTime 2014-11-13 11:00 $
*/
As
SELECT LastUsed.ClientID, LastUsed.LastUsedDate, LastUsed.Lab
FROM    (
            SELECT ClientID, MAX(DateReceived) AS LastUsedDate, 'Billings' AS Lab
            FROM BLSQL.EnergyBL.dbo.Workorders AS blwo
            GROUP BY ClientID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ClientID, MAX(DateReceived) AS LastUsedDate, 'Casper' AS Lab
            FROM CASQL.EnergyCA.dbo.Workorders AS blwo
            GROUP BY ClientID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ClientID, MAX(DateReceived) AS LastUsedDate, 'College Station' AS Lab
            FROM SRVCS.EnergyCS.dbo.Workorders AS blwo
            GROUP BY ClientID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ClientID, MAX(DateReceived) AS LastUsedDate, 'Gillette' AS Lab
            FROM GLSQL.EnergyGL.dbo.Workorders AS blwo
            GROUP BY ClientID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ClientID, MAX(DateReceived) AS LastUsedDate, 'Helena' AS Lab
            FROM SRVHE.EnergyHE.dbo.Workorders AS blwo
            GROUP BY ClientID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ClientID, MAX(DateReceived) AS LastUsedDate, 'Rapid City' AS Lab
            FROM SRVRC.EnergyRC.dbo.Workorders AS blwo
            GROUP BY ClientID
        ) AS LastUsed
WHERE ClientID = @ClientID
ORDER BY ClientID, LastUsedDate DESC
```

My mapping to execute the stored procedure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="Mirage.Domain.Old"
               namespace="Mirage.Domain.Old">

<sql-query name="ClientLastUsed">
    exec GetClientLastUsed :ClientID
</sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The method which uses the mapping:

```
    //return the date/time when the client was last used to create a workorder
    public ICollection<ClientLastUsed> GetLastUsed(string ClientID)
    {
        var finalResults = new List<ClientLastUsed>();

        using (ISession session = SessionHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            var results = session
                .GetNamedQuery("ClientLastUsed")
                .SetParameter("ClientID", ClientID)
                .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(ClientLastUsed)));

            finalResults = results.List() as List<ClientLastUsed>;

        }

        return finalResults;
    }
```

The class that gets the columns:

```
public class ClientLastUsed
{
    public virtual string ClientID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Lab { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? LastUsedDate { get; set; }
}
```

When the solution is run, a catch block returns the error "Procedure GetClientLastUsed has no parameters and arguments were supplied."

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What does a SQL profiler show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my mapping as suggested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="Mirage.Domain.Old"
               namespace="Mirage.Domain.Old">
<import class="ClientLastUsed" />
<resultset name="GetClientLastused">
<return-scalar column="ClientID" type="String" />
<return-scalar column="Lab" type="String" />
<return-scalar column="LastUsedDate" type="DateTime"/>
</resultset>

<sql-query name="GetClientLastUsed">
exec GetClientLastUsed :ClientID
</sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And method was changed to handle the suggested transform

```
//return the date/time when the client was last used to create a workorder
    public ICollection<ClientLastUsed> GetLastUsed(string ClientID)
    {
        var finalResults = new List<ClientLastUsed>();

        using (ISession session = SessionHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            var results = session
                .GetNamedQuery("GetClientLastUsed")
                .SetParameter("ClientID", ClientID)
                .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ClientLastUsed>()).List<ClientLastUsed>();

            finalResults = results as List<ClientLastUsed>;

        }

        return finalResults;
    }
```

After making those changes, the resulting query worked correctly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Mirage.Domain.Old" namespace="Mirage.Domain.Old">
<import class="ClientLastUsed"/>
  <resultset name="GetClientLastUsed">
    <return-scalar column="ClientID" type="String"/>
    <return-scalar column="Lab" type="String"/>
    <return-scalar column="LastUsedDate " type="DateTime"/>
  </resultset>
<sql-query name="GetClientLastUsed">
    exec GetClientLastUsed :ClientID
</sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this:

```
session.GetNamedQuery("GetClientLastUsed").SetString("ClientID", ClientID).SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ClientLastUsed>()).List<ClientLastUsed>();
```

Comment: After adding the updated code, there is an error with the finalResults = results.List() as List<ClientLastUsed>.
"'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Mirage.Domain.Old.ClientLastUsed>' does not contain a definition for 'List' and no extension method 'List' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Mirage.Domain.Old.ClientLastUsed>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: Could you please give me more information about SessionHelper class?